# How to display a div when values are selected from TWO dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here I have two dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Car Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="form-control" id="cartype" name="cartype">
           <option value=""> -- Select Type -- </option>
           <option value="Innova">Innova</option>
           <option value="Tata">Tata</option>
           <option value="Mahindra">Mahindra</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Rate Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="form-control" id="rate" name="rate" onchange="showdiv()" >
            <option value=""> -- Select Type -- </option>
            <option value="Outstation" name="outstation" id="outstation">Outstation</option>
            <option value="Local" name="local" id="local">Local</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

And a Text Box

```
<div class="form-group" id="showme" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
function showdiv(){
  var vehicle = document.getElementById("cartype").value = "Innova || Tata";
  var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value = "Local";   
  document.getElementById("showme").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Here I need to display the Text Box `div` only when cartype is equal to `Local`. But when I select `Rate Type` the hidden `div` is displaying.

Can you help me out where is the error in my code??

Comment: Why are u assiging values in ur showdiv() method? Arent u suppose to save `document.getElementById("cartype").value` this value instead of assigning ?

Comment: I have to select those values from dropdown

Comment: where? @SVinesh

Comment: Yu wan to show text box only when car type is Innova r toyata and rate is local right?

Comment: Yes. Only some cars in first dropdown & Local in second dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be working:

```
function showdiv(){
  var vehicle = document.getElementById("cartype").value;
  var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;

  if ((vehicle == "Innova" || vehicle == "Tata") && rate == 'Local') {
     document.getElementById("showme").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
     document.getElementById("showme").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: After submission of form when I fetch to edit this again. The hidden div is not coming. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should wrap the elements in form tag. <form method="POST">{html}</form>

Comment: I used `if else` condition while fetching & its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function showdiv(){
       if((document.getElementById("cartype").value == "Innova" || document.getElementById("cartype").value == "Tata") &&  (document.getElementById("rate").value == "Local")){
                document.getElementById("showme").style.display = 'block';
       } else {
       document.getElementById("showme").style.display = 'none';
       }


}
```

Comment: Not working. If I wont select first dropdown also div is displaying